# Error loading Fonts from outside of Eclipse (But works within Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having a problem loading a custom font when I run my Java program on the command line.  I receive the error messages:

> Reason (IOException): Can't read Resources/Fonts/customFont.ttf
>   
>   java.io.IOException: Can't read Resources/Fonts/customFont.ttf

However, when I run the program within Eclipse, the Font file is found.

The Font file is resident in the runnable Jar file created when I export my program from Eclipse.

Here is the code:

```
File aFile= new File("Resources/Fonts/customFont.ttf");
try {
        System.out.println("About to access: " + aFile.toString());
        font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, aFile);
} catch (FontFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Reason (FontFormat): " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Reason (IOException): " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
}

font = font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD,15);
```

Now, that was the latest way I've tried to get this to work from reading other people posts.

Here is the other way I've tried:

```
String filename="/Fonts/customFont.ttf";

Font font = null;
File aFile= new File(getURL(filename).getFile());
try {
        System.out.println("About to access: " + aFile.toString());
        font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, aFile);
} catch (FontFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Reason (FontFormat): " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Reason (IOException): " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
}

font = font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD,15);


private static URL getURL(String imageFilename) {
    URL aURL= null;

    aURL= Airplane.class.getResource(imageFilename);

    System.out.println("Got URL: " + aURL.toString());

     return aURL;
}
```

And got these error messages:

> Got URL: rsrc:Fonts/customFont.ttf
>
> About to access: Fonts/customFont.ttf
>
> Reason (IOException): Can't read Fonts/customFont.ttf
>
> java.io.IOException: Can't read Fonts/customFont.ttf
>
> at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1008)
>
> at Game.Screen.main(Screen.java:104)

Would appreciate any help with this!

Thanks!

Comment: if i don't make a mistake, within eclipse the root is the project. When you build your jar may be it's the location from where you launch it. So it will be better to use "getResourceAsStream" to search it into your classpath.

Comment: Objects in a jar are not files and you can't use `File` to access them. Use Class.getResourceAsStream

Comment: @greg-449 - I have been using the getImageURL calls to load .png files into ImageIcon calls, and they are working.  Although, the ImageIcom accepts a URL as a parameter.  The getImageURL call does invoke .getResource.  Now, I've tried experimenting with getResourceAsStream, but I need to turn it into a file, or at least have a File object as the result, as the createFont call wants a File object as the 2nd parameter.  I don't see how to do that.  Also, I need the solution to work both on the command line, and when running the program from within Eclipse.